# Laravel framework size

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I just downloaded laravel 4 via composer and i see that the size of the vendor folder 26mb.

After i checked all packages inside the vendor folder i saw that most of them have files that aren't needed in a live website, like tests or readme files.

I must delete those files manually or is there another way?

All those extra packages are required by laravel?

Laravel 3 was very simple, that is why i started using, i never thought a new update could be so different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how you installed via Composer you'll also have the Git history of each of those dependencies. You can drop the filesize even more by running `composer update --prefer-dist` to instead download archives instead of cloning the repository.

In the long run though, disk space isn't exactly expensive in this day and age. I can understand you might be a little concerned about it but you shouldn't worry too much. It doesn't have a huge impact on the overall performance of your application. If you optimize the Composer autoloader with `composer dump-autoload -o` and run `php artisan optimize` to generate a `bootstrap/compiled.php` file you'll still great excellent speed.

In comparison Laravel 3 is very simple. But Laravel 4 has embraced the future and ships with some awesome functionality.

At the end of the day there is no reason for you to upgrade to Laravel 4 if you don't see the need. You can safely continue to use Laravel 3 as it will be patched for any security vulnerabilities or bugs.

For more information on the number of files, see this [forum post](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=8175).

Comment: thanks. I will check this week Laravel 4 but i guess i will stick with Laravel 3